# Load div on the page one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#clr" ).each(function(i) {
    $("#clr"+id).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
   )};
});
</script>

<div class="row" id="clr">
        <a href="wishfinal/" class="custom" id="clr1"><span class="textstyle">WISHINDIA</span></a>
        <a href="shoutit/" class="custom" id="clr2"><span class="textstyle">SHOUTIT</span></a>
        <a href="snake/" class="custom" id="clr3"><span class="textstyle">SNAKE</span></a>
        <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr4"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
        <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr5"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
        <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr6"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
        <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr7"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I'm trying to load div one after another with some delay but unable to do so please help to do this

Comment: what does your posted code do?

Comment: What is `id` in your function? As there is only one element with the id of `clr` the each loop will only iterate once. If id is undefined nothing will work ofcourse

Comment: debugging 101: check developer tools console for errors - you have some simple syntax errors to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you would need to fix the syntax errors around the anonymous function passed to the `.each` function. Basically your closing `)` bracket for `.each` should come after the closing `}` of the anonymous function passed to it.

Then, instead of iterating on `#clr`, you should be iterating over `#clr > a` - meaning on the anchor tags rather than the div element.

Also you don't have to specify the selector inside the `.each` function. You can instead refer to the elements using `$(this)`.

Finally, you can either refer to the index of element inside `.each` as `id` or `i`. In the snippet below I have used `id`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clr > a").each(function(id) {
        $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000 * id).fadeIn(1850);
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="row" id="clr">
  <a href="wishfinal/" class="custom" id="clr1"><span class="textstyle">WISHINDIA</span></a>
  <a href="shoutit/" class="custom" id="clr2"><span class="textstyle">SHOUTIT</span></a>
  <a href="snake/" class="custom" id="clr3"><span class="textstyle">SNAKE</span></a>
  <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr4"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
  <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr5"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
  <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr6"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
  <a href="test/index.php" class="custom" id="clr7"><span class="textstyle">TESTING</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^="clr"]').each(function(i) {
        let $this = $(this);
        $this.fadeOut(0, function () {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.fadeIn(1850);
            }, 1000 * i);
        });
    )};
});
```